# Type error on mongodb 3

Tags: mongodb

When i try to insert data on `mongodb 3` through `command line`  it's showing following error

```
use video;
switched to db video
db.movies.insertOne({ "title": "Jaws", "year": 1975, "imdb": "tt0073195" });
```

> 2018-03-26T12:42:42.233+0530 E QUERY    TypeError: Property 'insertOne' of object video.movies is not a function at (shell):1:11`

but `video` db also not created

Please help me to rectify this problem.

Comment: I know this is too late but it would help somebody. You should update your mongoDB. Here you will find how to update: https://askubuntu.com/a/965317/815420

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB supports [db.collection.insertOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/) from version 3.2, please check your mongodb version by using the mongo shell command

`db.version()`

**References:**

- [insertOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/)
- [version](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.version/)

Comment: Thank you Clement.

Answer (score 4):

Try with db.movies.insert instead of db.movies.insertOne and check If it's working fine. If it's working then your mongo version is less than 3.2. If not then share your mongoDb console Screenshot.

Comment: Thank you vengatesh. It's version problem only